# Whats wrong with my houseplants?

Tags: houseplants

I live in a dorm. Until recently everything was perfectly green until the plants were placed by a window and had colors developing on them.

What is this?

Also the one has no leaves was left in a dark room for 3 weeks. Can it be saved?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add photos of the plants

Answer (score 1):

Under or overwatering could be equally/more to blame than the light your plants are receiving, depending on the plant.  In addition to evaluating the amount of light they're receiving, it might also benefit you to look for thrips, which can suck the color right out of your green, thriving plants.  Thrips are visible to the naked eye, but barely.  If your plant has is losing its vibrant green hues and turning grey, check for little dark dots about the size of a marker tip.